# Block any type of URL in textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I want to validate textbox value after user click on submit button. I want to check  is there any kind of URL present in text. If it is present it should throw an error . I need to block following all type of URL

```
example.com
www.example.com
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.com
```

**HTML code:**

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" OnServerValidate="ValidateNoUrls" ControlToValidate="Textbox1" ErrorMessage="URLs not allowed" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnsubmit_Click" Text="Sbumit"/>
</div>
```

**Backend code:**

```
protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Page.IsValid)
    {
        Response.Write("Textbox Validated");
    }
}
protected void ValidateNoUrls(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    bool res ;
    res = Regex.IsMatch(e.Value, @"(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w++]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?");

    if(res == true)
    {
        e.IsValid = false;
    }
    else
    {
        e.IsValid = true;
    }
}
```

Currently it is validating only `http://www.example.com` and  `https://www.example.com`. Can any one please help me out?

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @mjwills I don't think so. Because my problem was `x` and I have asked help for problem `x`. And I think SO is about helping on what user have tried so far. And for that if `y` is going to solve problem than I think it's not bad idea to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou every one for your help. Finally I solved using following code

```
protected void ValidateNoUrls(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    string pattern = @"^(http|https|ftp|)\://|[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z](:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*[^\.\,\)\(\s]$";
    Regex reg = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    e.IsValid = !reg.IsMatch(e.Value);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `System.Uri` for validation

```
protected void ValidateNoUrls(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    System.Uri result = null;
    e.IsValid = !System.Uri.TryCreate(e.Value, UriKind.Absolute, out result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well to answer your question, `((ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/)?[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w++]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?` matches all the URLs you mentioned. [Here's](https://regex101.com/r/06PUoA/1) a demo. Basically, just made the protocol part optional.

Comment: your expression is blocking all types of URL that i need to filter but it is also blocking normal text. It is returning false for text without URL